# _tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hola a todos actualmente estoy tratando de insertar x cantidad de Listboxs en cada Frame de un Notebook, en función de la cantidad de elementos dentro un diccionario y todo esto desde un bucle for, ahora bien he creado una función para que me imprima el nombre del listbox seleccionado, pero el problema es que solo me imprime el nombre de los listboxs que han sido creados en el último Frame, los que están creados en el primer Frame al seleccionarlos me salta el error. Disculpen si me explico fatal, pero soy muy nuevo en Python y realmente las palabras no son lo mío :). Sin más dilación me despido muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Aquí les dejo el código lo he resumido lo más que pude.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root=Tk()
note = ttk.Notebook(root)


def mostrar_nombre(event):
    nombrel = str((listbox .get(listbox .curselection())))
    print(nombrel)


lista1={"Pestaña1": ["nota1", "nota2"], "Pestaña2": ["block1","block2","block3"]}

tabs = []

for i in (lista1): # Introduce los frames dentro de la lista tabs[] para su futuro uso.

    tabs.append(ttk.Frame(note))

contador1=-1
contador2=-1

for i in (lista1):
    contador1 += 1

    numero= int(contador1)

    note.add(tabs[numero], text=i) # Comienza a crear los frames. i=Pestaña1- i=Pestaña2

    for e in(lista1[i]):

        contador2 += 1
        numero = int(contador1)

        global listbox
        listbox = Listbox(tabs[numero])
        listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", mostrar_nombre) # Comienza a asignar los listboxs a cada pestaña.

        for e in (lista1[i]):
            listbox.insert(END, e) # Asigna a cada listbox creado un nombre.

note.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios puntos a considerar:

- En la callback usas `listbox.get` y `listbox.curselection` , dónde **`listbox` es la variable global generada en el `for`**. Esto causa que el `Listbox` del que intenta obtener el índice es siempre el último creado en el ciclo (ultima asignación `listbox = Listbox(tabs[numero])`). Si intentas seleccionar en otro `Listbox` la callback será llamada pero intenta obtener la selecciona del último `Listbox` por lo comentado antes y no del que genera el evento, el cual no tiene item seleccionado y por tanto se produce la excepción comentada.

  La solución es usar el evento que la callback recibe como argumento y obtener la referencia al widget que lo lanza mediante:

  ```
    listbox = event.widget
  ```
- El evento `<<ListboxSelect>>` no solo es lanzado cuando se selecciona activamente un item, cualquier cambio en la selección del `Listbox` lo lanza. Por ejemplo, si se deselecciona el item también es generado el evento.
- Además, por defecto `tkinter.Listbox` **pierde la selección cuando otro widget la toma para sí**.

  Esto causa que cuando selecciona un item en una lista y a continuación seleccionas un item de otra lista se lanzan dos eventos, uno por la nueva selección y otro por la deselección del elemento de la lista anterior. La lista anterior queda sin un elemento seleccionado, por lo que `listbox .curselection()` retorna una tupla vacía y `get` falla a consecuencia de ello igual que antes al no proporcionarle un índice válido.

Tienes varias opciones para solventar el problema de los dos últimos puntos:

- Usar un condicional en la callback para filtrar aquellas llamadas fruto de la perdida de la selección:

  ```
  def mostrar_nombre(event):
      listbox = event.widget
      index = listbox.curselection()
      if index:
          value = listbox.get(index[0])
          print(value)
  ```
- Configurar los `Listbox` para que no pierdan la selección cuando se cambia de uno a otro. Esto se consigue mediante el atributo `exportselection` dándole un valor de `False`.

  Dejo un ejemplo de tu código con esta última opción, simplificando algunos aspectos del mismo de paso:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk
  from tkinter import ttk


  def mostrar_nombre(event):
      listbox = event.widget
      index = listbox.curselection()
      value = listbox.get(index[0])
      print(value)

  pestañas = {
              "Pestaña1": ["nota1", "nota2"],
              "Pestaña2": ["block1","block2","block3"]
             }

  note = ttk.Notebook()

  for pestaña, items in pestañas.items():
      frame = ttk.Frame(note)
      note.add(frame, text=pestaña)
      listbox = tk.Listbox(frame, exportselection=False)
      listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
      listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", mostrar_nombre)

      for item in items:
         listbox.insert(tk.END, item)

  note.pack()
  note.mainloop()
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  Si necesitas una lista de las referencias a los frames para el futuro, simplemente usa `append` en el mismo `for`:

  ```
  tabs = []

  for pestaña, items in pestañas.items():
      frame = ttk.Frame(note)
      tabs.append(frame)
      ....
  ```

Comment: @JFSevilla, Eres increíble se nota muchísimo que eres todo un experto en este tema, llevo 2 días tratando de solucionarlo pero la verdad es que me falta muchísimo conocimiento por delante soy muy nuevo en Python apenas llevo 1 mes y unos días, muchísimas gracias por el tiempo que te tomaste para escribir la respuesta y además una respuesta muy bien estructura y concisa, una ultima pregunta que IDE, framework y sistema operativo usas para programar en Python?

Comment: @J.M.C Pregunta, si quisieras imprimir ademas del value el nombre de la pestaña como haces? Gracias

Comment: Si alguien llega aquí y le interesa lo planteado por Martin en el comentario anterior, está respondido en la siguiente pregunta:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/280161/15089

Answer (score 0):

o solo en tu código puedes reemplazarlo por esto:

1. antes lo tenias así:

```
def mostrar_nombre(event):
    nombrel = str((listbox .get(listbox .curselection())))
    print(nombrel)
```

2. ahora solo debes ponerlo asi:

```
def mostrar_nombre(event):
    if listbox.curselection() != ():
        value = listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
        print(value)
```

ese error es cuando el listbox.get recibe una tupla vacía.

Comment: El "1. antes lo tenías así" no es necesario