# Imprimir item seleccionado de una ListBox y el nombre de la pestaña del Notebook a la que pertenece

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy buscando la forma de además de imprimir el value de cada listbox, me devuelva el nombre de la pestaña en la que me encuentro.
Tome el codigo del foro y le hice las modificaciones que necesitaba.
Trabajo en Python3

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

limit_before_list = [0]
max_posts_list = [0]
max_comments_list = [0]
limit_before = 'limit_before'
max_posts = 'max_posts'
max_comments = 'max_comments'


def mostrar_nombre(event):
    listbox = event.widget
    index = listbox.curselection()
    value = listbox.get(index[0])
    print(pestaña)  # Aca esta mi problema, me devuelve la ultima ingresada
    print(value)


pestañas = {
    limit_before: list(range(0, 160, 10)),
    max_posts: list(range(0, 410, 10)),
    max_comments: list(range(0, 4100, 100)),
}

note = ttk.Notebook()

for pestaña, items in pestañas.items():
    frame = ttk.Frame(note)
    note.add(frame, text=pestaña)
    listbox = tk.Listbox(frame, exportselection=False)
    listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
    listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", mostrar_nombre)

    for item in items:
        listbox.insert(tk.END, item)


note.pack()
note.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma muy simple es usar `functools.partial` para pasar el nombre de la pestaña al llamar a la callback:

```
import functools
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


limit_before_list = [0]
max_posts_list = [0]
max_comments_list = [0]
limit_before = 'limit_before'
max_posts = 'max_posts'
max_comments = 'max_comments'


def mostrar_nombre(pestaña, event):
    listbox = event.widget
    index = listbox.curselection()
    value = listbox.get(index[0])
    print(pestaña)  # Aca esta mi problema, me devuelve la ultima ingresada
    print(value)


pestañas = {
    limit_before: range(0, 160, 10),
    max_posts: range(0, 410, 10),
    max_comments: range(0, 4100, 100),
}

note = ttk.Notebook()

for pestaña, items in pestañas.items():
    frame = ttk.Frame(note)
    note.add(frame, text=pestaña)
    listbox = tk.Listbox(frame, exportselection=False)
    listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
    listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", functools.partial(mostrar_nombre, pestaña))

    for item in items:
        listbox.insert(tk.END, item)


note.pack()
note.mainloop()
```

Otra forma sería usar el propio evento y a partir el widget que lanza el evento, la listbox, obtener la referencia del padre (`Frame`) y a partir de él obtenemos su padre (el `Notebook`). Una vez que tenemos una referencia al notebook obtenemos la pestaña seleccionada con `Notebook.select()` y el nombre con `Notebook.tab(tab, "text")`:

```
def mostrar_nombre(event):
    listbox = event.widget
    index = listbox.curselection()
    value = listbox.get(index[0])
    notebook = listbox.master.master
    pestaña = notebook.tab(notebook.select(), "text")
    print(pestaña)
    print(value)
```

Comment: Perfecto! Siempre tan crack! Muchas gracias!! Abz

Comment: Si quisiera agregar todo el notebook dentro de mi ventana original como puedo hacer? Tengo mi ventana original (ventana = tk.Tk()) y quiero ingresar todo este notebook inside. @FJSevilla

Comment: `ttk.Notebook` no se diferencia de otros widgets, pasa al constructor el padre (`ventana`) como primer argumento, `note = ttk.Notebook(ventana)` y luego posiciona con `pack`/`grid`/`place` el notebook en tu ventana como harías con cualquier otro widget, por ejemplo: `note.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)`

Comment: note = ttk.Notebook(ventana) hace que me sustituya la pantalla actual que tango...

Comment: Martin me ha faltado decir que no hagas `note.mainloop()`, sino `ventana.mainloop()`. Eso si la forma de posicionar en el notebook puede variar en función de dónde quieres posicionarlo en la ventana, el ejemplo que doy con `pack`hace que se posicione dentro de `ventana` y ocupe todo su tamaño. Si en vez de agregarlo a la ventana en si directamente quieres agregarlo a un widget que tienes ya posicionado en tu ventana, por ejemplo un Frame, debes pasar éste al constructor  de Notebook y no `ventana`, es decir algo así `note = ttk.Notebook(frame_de_mi_ventana)`

Comment: Edite mi pregunta para que veas lo que construi a ver si estoy bien alineado a lo que me comentas

Comment: Si, en principio es correcto. ¿Tienes elementos previos en tu ventana o está vacía antes de agregar el notebook?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d1pz4gXwFRlUxJnDaquegnAujy0NaPl4 aca te dejo el codigo, El programa primero abre una ventana, y pide un csv (martin) si existe nos habilita la proxima parte y ahi agregas n o y. Luego pones generar JSON y ahi es cuando me cambia de ventana

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96402/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-martin-bouhier).